# How to include neccessary files to the output of independent client project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dependencies, projects-and-solutions

My solution consists of:

`Client` - startup project, UI layer. Depends on: `App`

`App` - library, application layer, assembler. Depends on: `Lib1`, ...

`Lib1` - library, business logic layer. Needs a specific file to work properly: `ThirdParty.dll`

I've added `ThirdParty.dll` to the `Lib1` project (`Add` > `Existing Item...` > `Add`) and set `Copy to Output Directory` property of dll file to `Copy Always`. Now the dll file is copied to the `Lib1` output and to the `App` output, but not to the `Client` output where I need it to be.

What is the right (simple? obvious?) way to copy `ThirdParty.dll` to the output of `Client` on each solution build?

**UPD**
`ThirdParty.dll` is not a reference. Actually, that's another reference dependence. My question is applied to any file that needs to be in the folder of running application.

Recorded video to be sure I'm doing it right: http://youtu.be/QwS2tOIc5yQ

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Add Existing Item as Link:**

I had a similar issue in `VS2010` and I kinda ended up adding the file as `Link` and updating its property to `Copy Always`.

In your case, in `CLIENT` project, add `ThirdParty.dll` as `Link` (Add > Existing Item > Add as Link) and set `Copy to Output Directory` property of dll file to `Copy Always`.
*Note*: It would copy the folder hierarchy from Project Node.

*Just for Reference:* I was actually using an open source [LibGit2Sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp) which required a dll (libGit2.dll) to be available in the output directory. Therefore, in the UI layer, which had added application layer containing `LibGit2Sharp.dll` as reference; I had to add `libGit2.dll` as a `Link` + `Copy Always`. This was recommended solution.

**Post Build:**

The other option could be to write a post build scripts for `CLIENT`

To know how the `Copy` on `MSBuild` works, you could refer to `Microsoft.Common.targets` file (should be available @ C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets in your system)

```
<Target
        Name="CopyFilesToOutputDirectory"
        DependsOnTargets="
            ComputeIntermediateSatelliteAssemblies;
            _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal;
            _CopySourceItemsToOutputDirectory;
            _CopyAppConfigFile;
            _CopyManifestFiles;
            _CheckForCompileOutputs;
            _SGenCheckForOutputs">
```

Comment: @astef Installing Visual Studio 2012 which doesn't have this bug is a bit better =)

Comment: @Jacob If you have a good understanding of how the standard  MSBuild targets are interleaved in a Visual Studio build, maybe you can look at this case and try to find out why VS2012 and VS2010 behaviors diverge when they build the same project. See my answer for the relevant parts of the log: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16848316/1497385

Comment: @Ark-kun: As I see, VS2010 uses MSBuild of .Net4.0 and VS2012 uses 4.5. I haven't been lucky to get a chance to work on VS2012, will surely check that out..

Comment: There is only one MSBuild.exe with .Net 4.0 and .Net 4.5 - `C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe`. There is no c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.5.*\. Also VS 2012 uses `C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets` - the same one as VS 2010.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy and it's strange that it didn't work for you. I've just checked and this works:

1. Add `ThirdParty.dll` to the `Lib` project.
2. The `Build Action` should be set to `Content` (the default value) !!!
3. Set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer` or `Copy always`
4. Reference `Lib` from `App`
5. Reference `App` from `Client`

This works in Visual Studio 2012, but doesn't seem to work in Visual Studio 2010.

VS2010:

```
Target "AssignTargetPaths" skipped. Previously built successfully.
Target "_SplitProjectReferencesByFileExistence" in file "C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "Test.ContentFiles\App\App.csproj" (target "GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems" depends on it):
Task "ResolveNonMSBuildProjectOutput" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)'=='true' and '@(ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration)'!='') was evaluated as ('true'=='true' and ''!='').
Done building target "_SplitProjectReferencesByFileExistence" in project "App.csproj".
Target "GetCopyToOutputDirectoryXamlAppDefs" in file "C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Xaml.targets" from project "Test.ContentFiles\App\App.csproj" (target "GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems" depends on it):
Task "AssignTargetPath"
Done executing task "AssignTargetPath".
Done building target "GetCopyToOutputDirectoryXamlAppDefs" in project "App.csproj".
Target "GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems" in file "C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "C:\Users\Ark-kum\Documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Test.ContentFiles\App\App.csproj" (entry point):
Task "MSBuild" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent)' != '' and '$(_GetChildProjectCopyToOutputDirectoryItems)' == 'true' and '%(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent.Private)' != 'false' and '$(UseCommonOutputDirectory)' != 'true') was evaluated as ('' != '' and 'true' == 'true' and '' != 'false' and 'false' != 'true').
Task "AssignTargetPath"
Done executing task "AssignTargetPath".
Done building target "GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems" in project "App.csproj".
Done executing task "MSBuild".
Task "AssignTargetPath"
Done executing task "AssignTargetPath".
Done building target "GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems" in project "Client.csproj".
Target "_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory" in file "C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "Test.ContentFiles\Client\Client.csproj" (target "_CopySourceItemsToOutputDirectory" depends on it):
Building target "_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory" completely.
Output file "bin\Debug\FileList.App.txt" does not exist.
Task "Copy"
Copying file from "Test.ContentFiles\App\FileList.App.txt" to "bin\Debug\FileList.App.txt".
```

VS2012:

```
Target "GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems" skipped. Previously built successfully.
Done executing task "MSBuild".
Task "AssignTargetPath"
Done executing task "AssignTargetPath".
Done building target "GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems" in project "Client.csproj".
Target "_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory" in file "C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "Test.ContentFiles\Client\Client.csproj" (target "_CopySourceItemsToOutputDirectory" depends on it):
Building target "_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory" completely.
Output file "bin\Debug\FileList.Lib.txt" does not exist.
Output file "bin\Debug\FileList.App.txt" does not exist.
Task "Copy"
Copying file from "Test.ContentFiles\Lib\FileList.Lib.txt" to "bin\Debug\FileList.Lib.txt".
Copying file from "Test.ContentFiles\App\FileList.App.txt" to "bin\Debug\FileList.App.txt".
```

Quote from the .target files:

```
============================================================
                                    GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems

Get all project items that may need to be transferred to the output directory.
This includes baggage items from transitively referenced projects. It would appear
that this target computes full transitive closure of content items for all referenced
projects; however that is not the case. It only collects the content items from its
immediate children and not children of children. The reason this happens is that
the ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration list that is consumed by _SplitProjectReferencesByFileExistence
is only populated in the current project and is empty in the children. The empty list
causes _MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent to be empty and terminates the recursion.
============================================================
```

Comment: Are you sure that after building solution `ThirdParty.dll` is copied to the `Client` output? I see it in `App` project output only.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I've specifically checked it. (I've used an image though, not .dll file.). Are you sure the `Build Action` for `ThirdParty.dll` is set to `Content`? I can zip and share my solution (VS 2012) when I get home.

Comment: Yes, `Build Action` is `Content`. Im using VS2010 - that could be it's bug? Look at my video, everything is very simple: http://youtu.be/QwS2tOIc5yQ

Comment: You're complicating things a bit with this style of debugging. Remove the file Just go to the `Client/bin/Debug` with Explorer. Right-Click on `Client` and select `Build`, then switch to Explorer and look at the new files.

Comment: I've confirmed that this works in VS2012, but doesn't work in VS2010. It's a bit strange and it's hard to tell which version is buggy. Neither version really supports the "baggage items from transitively referenced projects", but somehow VS2012 does this. VS2012 skips some build steps that "were previously build successfully" or because the `BuildingProject` property somehow strangely becomes false. VS2010 executes more targets and somehow loses the grandchild content files in the process.

Comment: +1 I didn't think this worked because I had only been using VS10. It works as expected in VS12/13.

Answer (score 1):

You could  use(in visual studio) Lib1 project Properties -> Build Events -> Post-build event command line.

In the "Post-build event command line" edit box type *copy* commands that will copy required files to the  Client output folder. In that editbox you can use various VS macros (Click "Edit Post Build" -> Macros)
Like this:

```
copy path\to\ThirdParty.dll  $(SolutionDir)Client\bin\Debug
```

Perhaps, you will need to "Build"->"Rebuild Solution" at first time.

Comment: Bad thing is that `Lib1` becomes dependant on `Client` project. I think that is wrong the same as making `Client` dependant on all this third-party files. If choosing between all bad solutions I'd prefer adding all files to `Client` (Add => Existing Item...)

Comment: In any case Client depends from Lib1(via App). if you don't need dependencies from any projects and build actions then simply copy manually all your third party resources to output folder at first time. Or use post build step on Client that will copy all stuff to Client's  directory.